# MySql- on duplicate key insert with string added

Tags: mysql

How to insert from one table to another and on duplicate key append
string to new row?

If i got table with values:
a
b
c

and want insert tablevith value:
a

i want append string like 'x' so i will get table with values:
a
b
c
xa

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
INSERT INTO aatest
SELECT IF(COUNT(a2.letter)=0,'a','xa')
FROM aatest a1
LEFT JOIN aatest a2 ON a1.letter = a2.letter OR a2.letter IS NULL
WHERE a2.letter = 'a'
```

Will literally do what you asked...but it's not a proper solution unless you have a very unique issue you're trying to solve. It will fail if 'a' comes up again in the list because 'xa' will already be there too. A two query solution would be much easier to do assuming you're executing this within PHP or something.

Hope this helps...if you provide more details I may be able to be more helpful.